# How can I prove that an exponential function minus an fraction function is a quasi-convex function?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

The function is given as follows:

$$f(n) = 3 \times \left ( \frac{1}{5} \right )^{6n} - \frac{5}{n + 1} + 4$$

where $n \geq 0$.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: The function is monotonically decreasing. This should give quasiconvexity.

Comment: Actually, it is not monotonically decreasing.

Comment: Oh yes, I see...